# Open txt files from a directory, compare the values, and output the top 15 in PHP

Tags: php, html

I recently designed a referral game website for the fun of it.

There's a simple MySQL user system with a email verification. It's using the UserCake user management system.

On top of this i added a php page that the user could give to "victims" that when they visit it they get "infected" and can infect other users or "victims". This page uses GET to get the username from the url. I have a folder that when a user registers it creates a file with 4 digits and then the username. (ex; 0000Username.txt) All the numbers are the same, it's just so that if a user discovers the folder they won't be able to find the files. There is also a txt file in the same format with IPS in the name. (ex; 0000IPSUsername.txt) The file when visited gets the username from the url, then checks if the text file for that username exists. If the username is present in the url, and a valid user it opens the IPS file and adds the IP of the visitor, then opens the user text file, takes the value and adds one to it, and saves. At the end it makes the difference between saying "You are infected, Username has infected (amount) people." or just you have been infected.

Now to what i need!

I need to add a hi-scores to the website so people can compete to be the one with the most "infections".

I thought i could use readdir to get a list of the files and open them with the value in an array, but i need it to also strip the username from the file name. It would be best if it just saves to a text file like "Username | value" because then i can add echo's of the html tags and have it include the file in the page i want it to be one.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious why you chose to do this with files instead of the MySQL database you are connected to?

Comment: @St. John Johnson - Great point. I was wondering that myself. Regardless, some people have a method to their madness.

Comment: I'm not familier with SQL, but i've messed with PHP for a few years now and decided to see if i could accomplish it this way.

Comment: @Moshe: And yet Hamlet died ;-) @Anon: Using the database would make concurrency issues easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Try  using an array and `count($array)` to count the files.

Stripping the values out is as simple as using PHP's `str_replace` function. More here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

With the 0000Username.txt file try using json.

```
// Get
$contents = file_get_contents('0000Username.txt');
$data = json_decode($contents); // PHP > 5.2.0


// Put
$data['username'] = 'Username';
$data['infectious'] = $data['infectious'] + 1;
$contents = json_encode($data); // PHP > 5.2.0
file_put_contents($contents);
```